# Where clause using some field is not returning any rows in phonegap

Tags: sql, cordova

I am finding one funny error but not sure whether that is my mistake or not. Below is my code for phonegap storage application. I have to fetch the records by one field in SELECT Query. If I try without where condition it s working but with where clause it is not working. Anyone have an idea on this?

```
function setDetailWordList()
{
  db.transaction(SetDetailWords);
}
function SetDetailWords(tx)
{
  alert("Qiuery executing...");
  alert('SELECT * FROM DW_Words WHERE word = "'+word+'"');
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DW_Words where word = "'+word+'"', [], SetDetailWordsSuccess); 
}
function SetDetailWordsSuccess(tx,results)
{
  alert(results.rows.length);
  $('#words').html("").listview('refresh');
  for (var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++)
  {
    $('#words').append('<li><a><div>'+results.rows.item(i).explanation+'</div></a></li>');
  }
  $('#words').listview('refresh');
  //AddEvents();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Are you getting any error?

Comment: I am not getting any error . the length is 0 by alert.

Comment: Can you add a watch or show the value of the "word" variable you are appending into the SQL statement. Is it properly set?

Comment: In the alert of query , its giving me the correct value with double quote